# Remove a extension from Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I thought I was going to use Box2d in my game but I won't use it anymore. How can I remove the extension? I was finding if someone has already made this question, but I didn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. You will only have to remove the dependencies from your projects.

Open your `build.gradle` file in the root folder of your projects and search for [these dependencies](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#box2d-gradle).

After that you will probably have to trigger a refresh in your IDE. For example in eclipse you do this via a rightclick in your project -> Gradle -> Refresh dependencies.